# htaccess question

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have setup htaccess but i want increase the length of the rule so i need to know can i bypass one files, its currently 4 but i want to extend to 11- file i want to bypass is called shorten.php
can i name a file that escapes the rule?

```
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI} \/([0-9a-z]{4})$ [NC]
RewriteRule   ^(.*) http://www.x/forward.php?%1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can exclude them with an additional `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^shorten\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/([0-9a-z]{4})$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.x/forward.php?%1 [L]
```

Now the matched path of `RewriteRule` must not be `shorten.php`.

Comment: don't forget changing `{4}` into `{4,11}` as well. Also, you want to skip `forward.php` itself. so try `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` instead (won't math any existing file).

Comment: thanks for 4,11 i clean forgot about that and only reading this now :)